# Как открыть файл, котороый находится выше по каталогу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

Путь питон скрипта: `папка1\папка2\скрипт.py`
из этого скрипта, с помощью `os.open`, надо открыть текстовый документ который лежит по пути
`папка1\текстовый файл.txt` как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Import**

```
from pathlib import Path
```

---

**Code**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
os.open(f'{BASE_DIR}/папка1/текстовый файл.txt')
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!